# Bash how does skip-completed-text work?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, options

### More concise version

With `"\t": menu-complete` in `~/.inputrc` create these two files,

```bsh
$ touch one.two.txt
$ touch one.four.txt
```

start writing the following,

```bsh
$ ls one
```

hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and you'll get

```bsh
$ ls one.four.txt
```

Now move the cursor to just before `four`, delete `four`, write only `t`, and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. You'll get

```bsh
$ ls one.two.txt.txt
```

Is there a way to prevent the duplicated `.txt` in this workflow?

### Original question

I use `menu-complete` bash function to cycle through completion when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and I'm happy with it. But the following has too often happened to me.

Suppose I'm looking for the file `longparthardtoremember.with.QQQQQQQ.extension` in a directory which contains the files

```
longparthardtoremember.with.AAAAAAA.nice.long.extension
longparthardtoremember.with.BBBBBBB.very.nice.long.extension
...
```

If I <kbd>Tab</kbd>-complete `$ long` the first filename will be inserted. At that point, I'd like to move to the middle of the filename, delete the `AAAAAAA` part, type `B`, and then <kbd>Tab</kbd>-complete again. If I do so, all the part after `BBBBBBB` is inserted as well, thus leading to a duplication of it, which I obviously don't want.

With `vi` editing mode, I'm quite quick in dealing with this (I quickly move to the repeated part and delete it), but it is still annoying.

By pure chance I've find the `skip-completed-text` bash option in bash's man page. Isn't this what I need? I've set it `on`, but I can't see any difference in the behavior of in-middle-of-work <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion. Have I misunderstood the man page?

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow what you want - maybe add a few steps and show the output on the command line?

Comment: @laktak, how's it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skip-completed-text` works this way (with your example `touch one.four.txt`):

```
$ ls one.four
#        ^ cursor is on the f
```

If you press tab with `skip-completed-text on` it will complete to

```
$ ls one.four.txt
```

If you press tab with `skip-completed-text off` it will complete to

```
$ ls one.four.txtour
```

So this setting does not help you when you edit the middle of the completion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> Now move the cursor to just before `four`, delete `four`, write only `t`, and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again.

do

move the cursor to just before `four`, write only `t`, then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> (the default for delete from cursor until end)